# Capturing a HTML DOM after a page has fully loaded - using a service

Tags: c#, html, service

We have a requirement to load HTML pages and capture the full HTML DOM after the page has executed the page load scripts and the page has loaded completely. This needs to be a server based approach because of potential volume and the need to spread this load across multiple machines.

We're hoping to do this in .NET without using any visual controls such as the Web Browser control as that would tie us to a STA environment and message pumps.

We can download HTML pages no problem, but what we can't do is wait until scripts etc, have completed executing and capture the content at that stage.

Maybe it's possible

- to use parts of the new Edge library to capture the DOM without
  rendering it to a canvas
- there may be some custom components available that would allow us to do this by emulating a hosting environment (aka browser) and allowing us access to the DOM once it has loaded.

Any information on solving this problem would be much appreciated, even if we need to move outside of the .NET world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually stumbled across a C# wrapper for [PhantomJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS) which looks like it should do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the functionality included in a web crawler. It may be possible to use [Abot](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot).

Comment: Yep I suppose it is basically a web-crawler, but a pretty focused one, but still need to manage 10's of thousands of pages. I had a look at the code there and Abot is basically doing what we are doing at the moment, get a HTTPWebResponse for the page. That will download the HTML content of the page alright, but there is no execution of java-script etc, that the page may contain, so it does not really suit our needs.

Comment: Reading more closely, now I see that [Javascript Rendering](https://abotx.org/Learn/JavascriptRendering) is a paid add-on provided by AbotX.